# How to get element with tag name '<ht:picture_source>' using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web-scraping, web-crawler

I trying to scrape google trends using this [RSS feed link](https://trends.google.co.in/trends/trendingsearches/daily/rss?geo=US)

However I couldn't able to get the element with tag name `<ht:picture_source>..</ht:picture_source>`.

I tried the below code :

```
$(".trigger").on("click",function() {
    $.ajax({
         url: "https://trends.google.co.in/trends/trendingsearches/daily/rss?geo=US",
         dataType: 'text',
         success: function(data) {

              let post_count = $(data).find('title').length;

              for(let counter = 1; counter < post_count; counter++) {
                  let image = $(data).find('ht:picture').eq(counter).text();
                  console.log(image);
              }
    
          
         }
    });
});
```

I get undefined or empty on the console.

Someone already checked this up on [GigHub](https://github.com/huginn/huginn/issues/2720) 2 years ago.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special characters like : need to be escaped in jQuery selectors.

```js
let image = $('body').find('ht\\:picture_source').eq(0).text();
console.log(image);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ht:picture_source>Text</ht:picture_source>
```

Comment: Bro, can you check this query also please . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72683656/how-to-add-tag-to-onesignal-using-android-web-view-app